# Android option menu remove on view pager

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, optionmenu

I'm using `view pager` tabs using `toolbar` as `android action bar`.

Now in one of my `tab` ,I'm creating a `menu` only for that `fragment` ,its working fine as i set has Option menu to true on that `fragment` .

Question is,how can i remove the menu when user slides to different `tab` or click on different `tab`.

what is the best procedure to do it.

***I'm creating option menu in fragment like this***

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.custommenu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

Comment: setHasOptionsMenu(false); to that specific fragment..

Answer (score 1):

you need to have `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in all your fragments

and override as below in all fragments

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    menu.clear();
   //fragment specific menu creation
}
```

And you need to add viewpager listner as well as suggested by @Madhav

Comment: Well i can,but i don't want to,cause in my main activity i have one or two default menus which are available for all the fragment,and some fragment specific menu,so i cant use menu.clear()

Answer (score 0):

In your mainactivity do this in your viewpager's addonpagechangelistener

```
 ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {

      // Do your work here
      // Set your menu from here according to the position
      // followed by invalidateoptionsmenu()


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
});
```

Comment: i already have an OnPageChangeListener,can you be more specific on how to remove the menu from on page selected ?

Comment: also please note that my min sdk version is 9,call to invalidateoptionsmenu() requires min api 11.

Comment: then use setHasOptionsMenu(false); in the oncreate of your fragment.

Comment: you can also use supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() instead of invalidateoptionsmenu()